# format function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

EDIT ON 18 June

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I use an administrative tool to connect to a database. For example, columns needed are id, year and month. I select the columns:

Document_Header.Document_id : pulls the column document_id from the table Document_Header. There is an extra calculation box to specify the format of that column and the expression is format$({column}).
Production.Date : this pulls the date from the Production  table. There is an extra calculation boox to pull the month in the date and the expression is : month({column}) to pull only the month. 
Production.Date : this pulls the date from the production table : this pulls the date from the Production  table. There is an extra calculation boox to pull the year in the date and the expression is : year({column}) to pull only the year.

Note: the expression contain the word 'column' and not the column names.

I am looking for the correct syntax of these expressions for SQL Server. I understand from Caldazar's answer that we don't use braces and we specify the column names.

Should the right syntax be:
format$(document_id)
year(Date)
month(Date)

I hope this makes it clearer.

Thanks,
Sabiha

ORIGINAL POST
I work with an administrative application to map database objects for use in other applications. One of the columns I map is an id that comes in an alpha numeric format (eg `XXX001XXXX10`).
I map the column in the application `format$({column})`. This is done with Access databases.

Now I want to do the same with a SQL database. I have to map an id that has alphanumeric characters.

I also use the same calculation for year : `year({column})` and month: `month({column})`.

What would be the equivalent of the access `format$({column})`, `year({column})` and `month({column})` in SQL?

Comment: Please specify which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: You also need to explain, what exactly `format$({column})` does for those who do not know MS-Access. Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, For dates, it's the same as in MS Access, so:

`year(column_name)` gives you year of the date you provided in that column

`month(column_name)` gives you month of the date you provided in that column

regarding format, that you mention, in both SQL server and MySQL you have format function. You can also use cast and convert.

SQL SERVER: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

MySQL: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_format.asp

Comment: `year()` and `month()` are specific to MySQL and SQL Server. Those are not standard SQL functions

Comment: Thanks. that was what I was looking for.